# How to zoom content with background image using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div>` whose content includes text and a background image.

How can I zoom the `<div>` by selecting content?
*(zooming text and background image)*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to zoom the content after a user selects its inner text?

Comment: i want to zoom the content(selected by user) with background image.

Answer (score 0):

On Particular Event use Add particular class and in that CSS Property write  transform:scale(6);

refer the JS Fiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ope432pL/1/

`setTimeout(function () {
    $('.intro_bg').addClass('zout');
}, 1000);`

In CSS Write `.intro_bg.zout {
    transform:scale(6);
}`